# Popup binding error

Tags: c#, wpf

My binding can't find the viewmodel. If it is a normal listbox things are fine. But I can't get it working when the listbox is in popup.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
  <viewModel:MyViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

  <Popup Name="MyPopUp" UseLayoutRounding="True" AllowsTransparency="False" IsOpen="True" Placement="Right">                                    
    <ListBox DataContext="viewModel:MyViewModel" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedListItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxContents}">
    </ListBox>
    </Popup>
```

In MyViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<double> ListBoxContents { get; set; }
public string SelectedListItem {get;set;}

ListBoxContents = new ObservableCollection<double>() {6,5,4};
```

Binding Error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ListBoxContents' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-734831200)'. BindingExpression:Path=ListBoxContents; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-734831200); target element is 'ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedListItem' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-734831200)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedListItem; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-734831200); target element is 'ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')
```

I checked for spelling mistakes. I'm learning about snoop to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
  <Popup Name="MyPopUp" UseLayoutRounding="True" AllowsTransparency="False" IsOpen="True" Placement="Right">
    <Popup.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MyViewModel/>
    </Popup.DataContext>    
    <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedListItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxContents}" />
  </Popup>
```

Comment: Thanks. The popup knows the datacontext now

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a string (`"viewModel:MyViewModel"`) as DataContext of your ListBox here :

```
<ListBox DataContext="viewModel:MyViewModel"  
         ....>
```

Hence binding error you got, string doesn't have property `ListBoxContents` nor `SelectedListItem`. I really suspect you meant to do binding there, instead of setting the value directly.

Anyway, the fix could be simpler, just remove `DataContext` setting from your `ListBox` to make it inherits parent's DataContext :

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
  <viewModel:MyViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Popup Name="MyPopUp" UseLayoutRounding="True" AllowsTransparency="False" 
       IsOpen="True" Placement="Right">                                    
    <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedListItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxContents}">
    </ListBox>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand better why I get the biding error.